# In R how to obtain a vector which would apply AND over all columns?

Tags: r

I am trying to apply AND over all columns of a matrix and could not find a similar question:

```
> array(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE),dim=c(2,3))
      [,1] [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

I am trying to obtain

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

By doing an AND over columns, how do I do that in R ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `all()`:

```
apply(x, 2, all)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

You didn't ask for it, but `any()` is the complement of `all()`:

```
apply(x, 2, any)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way I know of:

```
colSums(x) == nrow(x)
```

And if you are code-golfing, there is the more obscure

```
!colSums(!x)
```

Also, if your data only has two rows, you can just do the vectorized

```
x[1,] & x[2,]
```

All of these should be way faster than using a loop (`for` or `*apply`)

---

Finally, to get the result into a horizontal matrix, wrap everything into `t(...)` or `matrix(..., nrow = 1)`.